# Finding a date in a long string using PHP

Tags: php, parsing

I have a collection of documents and I'm trying to pull the dates out of them. They are plain text and HTML mostly but the date formats they use very greatly (though they are all English dates). How can I find and parse dates like this in a long string of text?

```
updated 2011-03-21T00:43:14
Sunday, March 20, 2011
Wednesday, March 16, 2011 | 11:25 AM
March 20, 2011 @ 12:21 pm
May 5, 2011
Published March 19, 2011
Some text here (March 19, 2011)
10/28/2011 21:16
<a href="#>Author Name</a> on Mar 17th 2011 ...
Location, ABBR., Jan. 8, 2008
01/07/2008 (6:00 pm)
By Author Name and Company 03/19/2011 09:59
Posted by Author Name on March 16, 2011 at 03:20 PM EDT
```

Comment: I will not answer, just give an advice. This is definitely regexp task. If set of possible date formats is limited, you should write your own small class/method. Look at http://www.functions-online.com/preg_match_all.html and post there a sample text - it can help you greatly.

Comment: @MOleYArd, I took your advice and resorted to regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) function.

```
// Output: March 20th, 2011 12:00:00 AM
echo date( 'F jS, Y h:i:s A', strtotime( "Sunday, March 20, 2011"));
```

**Edit:** Here is a more complete example showing how to parse a bunch of the dates provided.

```
<?php
$dates = array( '03/19/2011 09:59', 'Wednesday, March 16, 2011 | 11:25 AM', 'Sunday, March 20, 2011', 'March 20, 2011 @ 12:21 pm', 'May 5, 2011');
foreach( $dates as $date)
{
    echo $date . ' ---- ' . date( 'F jS, Y h:i:s A', strtotime( str_replace( array( '@', '|'), '', $date))) . "<br />\n";
}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/yCEQqm)

Of course, some dates will not parse as-is since they are not supported by the list of [date formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) - For those, you'll need to do some additional filtering / parsing to either extract their date or form them into a string suitable for strtotime.

**Edit:** Since there's an interest in further processing of the input string, here is an example of how you can parse the text without using a regex to get the dates out. Notice how some of the dates just can't be extracted, for this you will either need more string processing, or to use a regex.

As a side note, I would investigate using a regex if the provided string is only one of many variants of lines that contain dates. However, if the provided string is the only formats that the dates will be found in, string processing should be enough.

```
$str = 'updated 2011-03-21T00:43:14
Sunday, March 20, 2011
Wednesday, March 16, 2011 | 11:25 AM
March 20, 2011 @ 12:21 pm
May 5, 2011
Published March 19, 2011
Some text here (March 19, 2011)
10/28/2011 21:16
<a href="#">Author Name</a> on Mar 17th 2011 ...
Location, ABBR., Jan. 8, 2008
01/07/2008 (6:00 pm)
By Author Name and Company 03/19/2011 09:59
Posted by Author Name on March 16, 2011 at 03:20 PM EDT';

foreach( explode( "\n", $str) as $line)
{
    $line = str_replace( array( '@', '|', '(', ')'), '', trim( $line));
    $line = strip_tags( $line);
    if( ($time = strtotime( $line)) === false)
    {
        echo "Could not parse line - '" . $line . "'\n"; // Need additional processing / regex here
        continue;
    }
    echo "Converted '" . $line . "' to '" . date( 'F jS, Y h:i:s A', $time) . "'\n";
}
```

[Demo.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/oDPXrN)

**Final Edit:**

Finally, an example how to do some text processing to get more of the dates to parse.

```
foreach( explode( "\n", $str) as $line)
{
    $line = str_replace( array( '@', '|', '(', ')', 'Published', '...'), '', trim( $line));
    $line = strip_tags( trim( $line));
    if( ($time = strtotime( $line)) === false)
    {
        if( !(($on_position = stripos( $line, 'on')) === false))
        {
            $line = substr( $line, $on_position + 3);
            if( ($time = strtotime( trim( $line))) === false)
            {
                echo "Could not parse line that contains 'on' - '" . $line . "'\n";
                continue;
            }
        }
        echo "Could not parse line - '" . $line . "'\n";
        continue;
    }
    echo "Converted '" . $line . "' to '" . date( 'F jS, Y h:i:s A', $time) . "'\n";
}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/j8OSQz)

Comment: -1 There are lots of date formats in there which `strtotime()` won't handle. `March 20, 2011 @ 12:21 pm` for example.  Also `March 16, 2011 | 11:25 AM`

Comment: @Michael - Of course `strtotime()` won't parse every date, but it can handle those and many others just find with a bit of preprocessing. I was in the process of updating my answer with a more complete demonstration, which you can see correctly parses both of those dates and others.

Comment: How do you propose to extract those dates from their context in the lines? This answer is still far from complete.

Comment: Because the complete solution is outside of the scope of a single question - This is one method of converting strings to dates, a legitimate use case for the question. Extracting all of the dates requires heavy text parsing or a very complicated regex, which I don't think you expect me to formulate, do you? My answer is a base solution to the bigger problem.

Comment: Still waiting for your solves-it-all solution, @Michael. I'm giving *this* answer a +1 for the time being.

Comment: Please use a `<pre>` tag to make your output readable. http://codepad.viper-7.com/pKyjbh and http://codepad.viper-7.com/q9kYP5

Comment: @JaredFarrish - Thanks for the tip! I usually click the "Source" link instead.

Comment: @Michael, I posted an answer that handles all the use-cases I could think up. Perhaps you guys could expand on that.

Answer (score 2):

I had a little time tonight so I played around with some regex knowing that I was looking for a digit grouping. The following parses everything below just fine. Also, the foreach is just for an example. The regex is built for `preg_match_all()` so you should be able to pull all dates from a string with no problem.

```
$str = 'updated 2011-03-21T00:43:14
Sunday, March 20, 2011
Wednesday, March 16, 2011 | 11:25 AM
March 20, 2011 @ 12:21 pm
May 5, 2011
Published March 19, 2011
Some text here (March 19, 2011)
10/28/2011 21:16
<a href="#">Author Name</a> on Mar 17th 2011 ...
Location, ABBR., Jan. 8, 2008
01/07/2008 (6:00 pm)
Published under recent news one March 17, 2011. Now onto other things!
By Author Name and Company 03/19/2011 09:59
Posted by Author Name on March 16, 2011 at 03:20 PM EDT';

$months = array(
    'jan', 'january',
    'feb', 'febuary',
    'mar', 'march',
    'apr', 'april',
    'may',
    'june',
    'july',
    'aug', 'august',
    'sept', 'september',
    'oct', 'october',
    'nov', 'november',
    'dec', 'december',
);

header('Content-Type: text/plain');

foreach(explode( "\n", $str) as $line)
{
    $line = str_replace(array('@', '|', '(', ')', 'at', 'on', 'am', 'pm'), '', mb_strtolower(trim($line)));

    if(preg_match('/([a-z]+[, .]+)?(\d.+?)\D*?$/m', $line, $match))
    {
        $date = '';

        // Is that word a valid month?
        if(in_array(trim($match[1], ',. '), $months))
        {
            $date = $match[1];
        }

        $date .= $match[2];

        if( ($date = strtotime($date)) !== false)
        {
            echo "Converted '" . $line . "' to '" . date( 'F jS, Y h:i:s A', $date) . "'\n";
            continue;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        print "Failed to find anything\n";
    }

    echo "Could not parse line - '" . $line . "'\n"; // Need additional processing / regex here
}
```

This is rather hacky feeling, perhaps someone can still answer with a better parser.